# How to determine the return type of a method from the class it is implemented in?

Tags: java

I have a set of classes that are used to store data for which I am currently trying to implement a deep copy mechanism. For this, I would like to define a method `deepCopy()` in my abstract class which every extending class needs to implement.

I am struggling with defining the abstract method in a generic way so that every `deepCopy()` returns an Object of the class it was implemented in.

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract Foo deepCopy();
}

public class Bar extends Data {
    @Override
    public Bar deepCopy() {
        //copying;
    }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve, but I end up with this:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract Foo deepCopy();
}

public class Bar extends Data {
    @Override
    public Foo deepCopy() {
        //copying;
    }
}
```

This causes an error when calling `deepCopy()`:

```
public SomeClass extends Foo {
    private Bar value;

    private SomeClass(final SomeClass original) {
        this.value = original.deepCopy(); // type-mismatch since deepCopy returns Foo but value is Bar.
    }

    @Override
    public Foo deepCopy() {
        return new SomeClass(this);
    }
}
```

The simplest way to resolve this would be to cast the returned object of deepCopy to Bar, but this seems wrong.

Is there a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: Aside from the fact that it's rather broken, what's wrong with using `clone`?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Everytime I am gathering information on deep copying objects I read that using clone should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that covariant return types would solve the issue here:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract Foo deepCopy();
}
```

Then `Bar` can return a `Bar` from the method:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public Bar deepCopy() {
        //copying;
    }
}
```

So:

```
final Bar bar = new Bar();
final Bar barCopy = bar.deepCopy(); // <- Bar's deepcopy returns a Bar
final Foo foo = ((Foo) bar).deepCopy(); // <- Foo's deepcopy returns a Foo
```

The is allowed because as `Bar extends Foo` you can use a `Bar` wherever you would be allowed to use a `Foo`. So a subclass can override methods from a superclass that return covariant types.

This would work in the more general case:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public abstract Number getThing();
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public Integer getThing() {
        //copying;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Bar.getThing` returns an `Integer` but it overrides the method `Foo.getThing` which returns a `Number`. This is fine because we can use `Integer` wherever we can use `Number`.

Comment: Wow. Always amazes me how simple things can be. Thanks, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Generics in java.

Implement the class like this.

```
public abstract class Foo<Item> {
    public abstract Item deepCopy();
}
```

You can read about generics here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Yeah, I tried using generics and ended up with public abstract class Foo<T extends Foo>  using T as the return value of deepCopy(). But this ends in an extending class that looks like public class Bar<Bar> {} which just looks plain wrong. Is this just me being overcautios or really wrong?